# backbone/marionette attaching HTML into a region

Tags: templates, backbone.js, marionette

I'm beginning to use Marionette within an existing backbone application. I've got some HTML which I want to append into a region. In pure backbone, I could just do `this.$el.append(html_code)` and that was all. As far as I can see, marionette regions allow only to operate on views (which have to implement the `render` method). Calling `append` on marionette region throws 'undefined method' errors.

Is it possible to attach plain HTML to a marionette region?

Comment: In case you were wondering, this has actually been a suggested enhancement to the framework: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/2317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a Marionette ItemView will look for a template and will call render on that template, so when you show the view in the region the html will be displayed just fine with out the need of you defining a render method.

```
MyImtemView = Backbone.Marionete.ItemView.extend({
    template : "#myTemplate"  
});

var myItemView = new MyItemView();
myLayout.aregion.show(myItemview);
```

this should work if you save your html in a template like this

```
`<script id="myTemplate" type="text/template">
  <div><p>your html<p>
  </div>
```

`

EDIT

you can also declare a render function in your view in case you need to generate and modify your html like this.

```
MyImtemView = Backbone.Marionete.ItemView.extend({
    template : "#myTemplate",
    render : function (){
       this.$el.append(HMTL); //so here you work your html as you need


    }
});

var myItemView = new MyItemView();
myLayout.aregion.show(myItemview); //the render function of your view will be called here
```

Comment: I see your point. But is it really the only way to wrap a plain HTML with a marionette view? Is there no way to do it directly?

Comment: you can also declare a render method in the itemView that will be called when when you show your view in the layout. in this render you can create the html and modify it as you want, but yeah, the view is the responsible of rendering the html, and the region will display this view into your layout.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's not what I expected to get, but [1] probably there's nothing more in marionette and you deserve a vote up, [2] possibly if I've got such a strange case, I may have an architectural issue and I should try to find a different solution.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to inject plain html into a *Marionette.Region*.

Theoretically you could access a regions DOM element with `someRegion.el` or `someRegion.getElement()`, but this must be done after rendering (which at least isn't possible inside a *Marionette.View* with standard behaviour).

But you can achieve the desired result by using a specially crafted *Marionette.ItemView*:

```
@someRegion.show(new Marionette.ItemView({template: '<h1>gach</h1>'}));
```

---

You maybe also should have a look at [*Marionette.Renderer*](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.renderer.html) .

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and tried the answers explained here, but I'm also using require.js and kept getting an error for the #my_view template not being found. If anyone can clarify where does Marionette look up the templates by default, that would be great.

Instead, I solved it by using the text.js plugin for underscore.js. This way you actually *can* use a plain html file as the template, *without* the need for nesting it in a script tag. Here's how I did it.

```
define(['backbone', 'underscore', 'marionette', 'text!tmpl/my_view.html'], function(Backbone, _, Marionette, view_t){

    var MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        template : function(serialized_model) {
            //define your parameters here
            param1 = erialized_model.param1;

            return _.template(view_t)({
                param1: param1
            });
        }
    });
    return MyView;
});
```

I placed the text.js plugin in the same lib directory as all my other js libraries and my main.js for require declares the path to the templates as

```
'tmpl':     '../../templates',
```

My project structure looks like this

```
root
    index.html
    js
        main.js
        app
             App.js
             views
                 MyView.js
        lib
            require.js
            text.js
            backbone.js
            underscore.js
            jquery.js
            backbone.marionette.js
    templates
        my_view.html
```

My template 'my_view.html' simply looks like this.

```
<h1>THIS IS FROM THE TEMPLATE!!!</h1>
```

Worked perfectly. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

### Using a view

```
var myHtml = '<h1>Hello world!</h1>';
var myView = new Marionette.ItemView({template: _.constant(myHtml)});
myRegion.show(myView);
```

`Marionette.Renderer.render` takes either a function or the name of a template ([source code](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette.html#section-209)). [_.constant](http://underscorejs.org/#constant) creates a function that returns the passed-in parameter.

### Attaching HTML

Alternately, the docs for `Marionette.Region` mention overriding the `attachHtml` method, see [Set How View's el Is Attached](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.region.html#set-how-views-el-is-attached).